# Loading in large text file (50,000+ lines, ~8MB) causes my program to stop?

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, getline, outofrangeexception

Answered:

changing

```
while (tracefile->good()){
    getline(*tracefile,line);
....
```

to

```
while(getline(*tracefile, line)){
....
```

did the trick. Thank you, @pmr.

Original:

I made a cache simulator for my computer architecture class which is supposed to read in a trace file that contains memory instructions for my cache.

I used a test trace file with only 1000 lines when making the program, but the actual trace files are 50k+ lines. With the test trace, the program runs perfectly. With the actual trace, the program continues until it tries to use .substr() on a line, which causes an out_of_range exception and stops my program prematurely. I investigated and found that getline() is giving empty strings when the trace is too big. Remember, this does not happen on traces <= ~5000 lines.

Does anyone know why this is happening? I am using an ifstream if that matters.

EDIT: sorry here is the code. It doesn't get past the "...."

main:

```
cout << "Program started.\n";
string str[6];
int i = 0;
/* check for the correct number of arguments */
if(argc != 3){
    cout<<"usage: "<< argv[0] <<" <configfile> <tracefile>\n";
    exit(0);
}
string confname = argv[1];
string tracename = argv[2];
/* open the files and check if it worked */
ifstream confile;
ifstream tracefile;

confile.open (argv[1], ios::in);
if (!confile.is_open()){
    cout<<"Could not open config file.\n";
    exit(0);
}
if (confile.is_open()) cout << "Config file loaded.\n";
tracefile.open (argv[2], ios::in);
if (!tracefile.is_open()){
    cout<<"Could not open trace file.\n";
    exit(0);
}
if (tracefile.is_open()) cout << "Trace file loaded.\n";
/* read in the data from the config file */
if (confile.is_open()){
    i = 0;
    while(confile.good() && i != 6){
        getline(confile, str[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

/* create the cache simulator */
cache csim(atoi(str[0].c_str()), atoi(str[1].c_str()), 
                atoi(str[2].c_str()), atoi(str[3].c_str()), 
                atoi(str[4].c_str()), atoi(str[5].c_str()));
cout << "Simulator started.\n";

/* send the simulator the trace */
csim.trace(&tracefile);
```

csim.trace:

```
cout << "Going through trace...";
int i;
string line;
string tag, index, offset;
this->IC = 0;
/* loop until there is no more lines */

while (tracefile->good()){
    /* get the next line and increment the instruction counter */
    getline(*tracefile,line);
    this->IC++;

    /* convert hex address to a binary address */
    string address = "";
    for (i = 0; i < line.substr(4,8).length (); i++)
    {
....
```

Comment: Please show the code that crashes -- otherwise helping you is hard.

Comment: Thanks, @pmr. I actually noticed that right after I typed that. It seems a little unusual to pass a stream as a pointer. Most people pass them as references.

Comment: Don't use the stream member `good`, but simply check the result of getline, e.g. `while(getline(*tracefile, line))`.

Comment: @pmr would `while(getline(*tracefile, line))` terminate once the eof is reached? Also, remember that my code runs perfectly if the tracefile is not too big.

Comment: OP, you are also doing `line.substr(4,8).length()` without checking to see if `line.length()` is at least 12. Also, unless I'm missing something, `line.substr(4,8).length ()` will either cause a crash or be equal to 8. What's the point of that?

Comment: @Geoff_Montee line.substr(4,8).length() returns 0x1fffff50 from the line `s 0x1fffff50 1`. It starts at position 4 and goes 8 characters. Remember, this code works perfectly fine on small trace files.

Comment: I don't think so, OP. `line.substr(4,8)` would return `0x1fffff50` and `line.substr(4,8).length()` would return `8`.

Comment: @user1763898 Yes, it will. I'm just pointing out things that make the code easier to read and more obviously correct.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee ah I misunderstood you. I changed it to just 8, and the code still fails.

Comment: @pmr I changed my while loop conditional to `while(getline(*tracefile, line))` like you suggested and my code now works. I don't know why, but it does. Thank you!

Comment: The documentation says that `istream::good` returns false when EOF is reached: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/good/ so maybe you had a trailing new line at the end of the file that caused an empty string to be read. My error checking I suggested should have prevented that/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one of your strings might not be long enough.

```
while (getline(*tracefile,line);){
    /* get the next line and increment the instruction counter */

    this->IC++;

    /* convert hex address to a binary address */


    //be sure to check length of string
    if (line.size() < 12)
    {
        cerr << "line is too small" << endl;
        continue;
    }

    string address = "";

    string tmp_str = line.substr(4,8);

    for (i = 0; i < tmp_str.size(); i++) //tmp_str.size() will always be 8
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I added that code and it only triggers on large trace files. If I take the exact same trace file, trim it down to ~5000 lines instead of ~50000, and use it instead, that code does not trigger.

Comment: What do you mean "triggers"? Do you mean that when you add the above error code, you get error messages saying "line is too small" only with large files? Please be more specific.

Comment: Please note that the important part is not the `tmp_str.size()` in the for loop. The important part is the `if (line.size() < 12)`.

Comment: I changed my while loop conditional to `while(getline(*tracefile, line))` like @pmr suggested and my code now works. I don't know why, but it does.